# Scraping Headlines From News Website Homepages Using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract headlines from the homepage of multiple news websites using BeautifulSoup. I am learning Python but do not have much knowledge on HTML, CSS of Javascript, so I use some trial and error using Inspect on Chrome. Here is the code for I wrote for doing this on the New York Times web page:

```
import requests from bs4
import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.nytimes.com/"
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, features="html.parser")
headlines = soup.find_all(class_="css-1vynn0q esl82me3")

for item in headlines:
    if len(item.contents) == 1:
        print(item.text)
    elif len(item.contents) == 2:
        print(item.contents[1].text)
```

Here are my questions:

1. As I plan to do this for multiple news websites, is there a better solution than this approach which you can suggest?
2. I have noticed that the CSS tag has been changed since I wrote this code, due to which I had to update it. Is there any solution which will not require me to change the code every time the tags are updated?

Comment: I think spending some time getting to know the DOM would help you immensely. CSS selectors are somewhat of an art form and will propel you to amazing height here. Here's a fan favorite training tool for you to get started! https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: To answer #2... no, web scraping is a bit of a cat and mouse game in that sense. I looked at the source for nytimes and they unfortunately don't use many of the semantic tags introduced in HTML5 (article, title etc.). I might look for `h2` and `.balancedHeadline` children of `section` tags to start.

Comment: @rgk This was an interesting tool. Any more suggestions to learn more after completing this one?

Comment: IIRC the tutorial is a pretty comprehensive review of the tools at your disposal. There are some specialty selectors (like the infamous "lobotomized owl"), but for the most part this is a matter of practice at this point. In Chrome's developer tools, you can experiment by adding new selectors in real time with the + icon. Here's a screenshot of selecting the headlines from NYT using my last suggestion: https://i.imgur.com/ARtrJIa.png

Comment: One thing to remember is that CSS prefers specificity, so more specific rules will always take precedence over less specific rules! `span {color:red}` will take a backseat to `body span {color: blue}` even though both apply to all `span` elements.

Comment: As the DOM returned via requests is different from the browser, I would suggest to use Selenium. I tried to scrap with Requests but the number of h2 is different from what observed from the browser

Comment: @YY I am trying to learn more about using Selenium. Is this a good resource to get started: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ ? Let me know if you know any other place to get started.

Comment: To answer #1: use rss... now #2 isn't applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, as you can find the `<script>` tags within the html, and then parse that as json format. It may not work specifically with every news website, as there will most likely be different tags/code to identify the headline tags, but you can have a genaral working code to pull these headlines even as they update later.

Parse the html as you normally would:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.nytimes.com/"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")
```

Then find all the `<script>` tags. The one we would want starts with the text `window.__preloadedData =` , so we'll just want to search that out from the 14 elements it finds with the `<script>` tag:

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'preloadedData' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
```

After it finds it, we'll store it as `jsonStr`, and then start to trim off the begining and end parts of the string to change this into pure json format that can then be loaded using `json.loads()`, and store that as our `jsonObj`:

```
    jsonStr = jsonStr.split('=', 1)[1].strip()
    jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';', 1)[0]
    jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Once we have the `jsonObj`, we'll iterate through the key:values within the structure to find the values associated with the `headline` key in the json object:

```
for ele, v in jsonObj['initialState'].items():
    try:
        if v['headline']:
            print(v['headline'])
    except:
        continue
```

**Full Code:**

I also added a date time element, as you might want to store that to see what the headlines were at specific dates/times as it updates later.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import datetime

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.nytimes.com/"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y  %I:%M %p')

r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'preloadedData' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('=', 1)[1].strip()
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';', 1)[0]
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
 

print ('%s\nHeadlines\n%s\n' %(url, now))
count = 1
for ele, v in jsonObj['initialState'].items():
    try:
        if v['headline'] and v['__typename'] == 'PromotionalProperties':
            print('Headline %s: %s' %(count, v['headline']))
            count += 1
    except:
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.nytimes.com/
Headlines
Thursday, March 07, 2019  11:50 AM

Headline 1: The Trade Deficit Set a New Record. For Trump, That’s a Failure.
Headline 2: Rules Relaxed for Banks, Giving Wall Street a Big Win
Headline 3: Biden’s Candidacy Plan is Almost Complete. Democrats Are Impatient.
Headline 4: Why Did Four Top Democrats Just Say No to 2020?
Headline 5: Why Birthrates Among Hispanic Americans Have Plummeted
Headline 6: The Top 25 Songs That Matter Right Now
Headline 7: Cohen Says Papers Prove His Lies Were Aided by Trump Lawyers
Headline 8: Paul Manafort to Be Sentenced Thursday in 1 of 2 Cases Against Him
Headline 9: Trump’s Lawyer Says Several Have Sought Presidential Pardons
Headline 10: Senator Says She Was Raped in the Military, Describing a Broken System
Headline 11: Your Thursday Briefing
Headline 12: Listen to ‘The Daily’
Headline 13: Listen: ‘Modern Love’ Podcast
Headline 14: In the ‘DealBook’ Newsletter
Headline 15: What if the Mueller Report Demands Bold Action?
Headline 16: Ilhan Omar Knows Exactly What She Is Doing
Headline 17: How to Think About Taxing and Spending Like a Swede
Headline 18: Even Google Can No Longer Hide Its Gender Pay Gap
Headline 19: Questions For and About Jared Kushner
Headline 20: The Big Race: It’s Time for a Rhyme
Headline 21: Listen to ‘The Argument’: How Does the Catholic Church Redeem Itself?
Headline 22: We Will Survive. Probably.
Headline 23: A Peace Plan for India and Pakistan Already Exists
Headline 24: Ilhan Omar, Aipac and Me
Headline 25: The India-Pakistan Conflict Was a Parade of Lies
Headline 26: Seven Buds for Seven Brothers
Headline 27: This Tech Makes D.I.Y. Key Duplication Easy. Maybe Too Easy.
Headline 28: 36 Hours in St. Augustine
```

Comment: trying the above code resulted in the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\pythonCodes\17_readWebPages.py", line 94, in <module>
    for ele, v in jsonObj['initialState'].items():

NameError: name 'jsonObj' is not defined

Comment: it's possible you need to add the headers paramter to the `requests.get()`. I updated the code, try now and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried and gave me the same error:   Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\pythonCodes\untitled0.py", line 34, in <module>
    for ele, v in jsonObj['initialState'].items():

NameError: name 'jsonObj' is not defined

Comment: this is weird, because it gave me NameError: name 'jsonObj' is not defined, which is defined above!!

Comment: well it only will be defined `if 'preloadedData' in script.text`. so it means for some reason, you aren't getting the html.